# how do I get the value form check box, ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I need to save the value of the check box but its not working

html:

```
<ion-checkbox  value="2" checked="true" ng-model="data.agreed">
                By selecting this...
                </ion-checkbox>
```

app.js

```
$http.post(link, { agreed: $scope.data.agreed });
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not working?

Comment: its not getting the value of the check box,  is there a different way to do it?

Comment: In your controller add this line`$scope.data = {agreed: false};` 

Then try it. Objective is to have this variable initialized before you do any changes to anything. Then you can use click events to modify the value

Comment: currently I"m getting the value of 1,  can I change this to true or false?

Comment: If you are getting a value already, my suggestion won't help you. Can you describe what you want to achieve and what is your current output and what is your expected output?

Comment: my output is 1 but I want true or false

Comment: `var newVal = $scope.data.agreed === 1 ? true: false;`

Comment: Can I do this?     $http.post(link, { agreed: $scope.data.agreed === 1 ? true: false });

Comment: Yes it will. I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try follow either one, You will get solution,**

```
<ion-checkbox  ng-checked='data.agreed === "true"'
               ng-model="data.agreed" 
               ng-true-value="'true'" 
               ng-false-value="'false'"
>
By checked value {{data.agreed}}
</ion-checkbox>


<ion-checkbox  ng-checked='data.agreed === "1"'
               ng-model="data.agreed" 
               ng-true-value="'1'" 
               ng-false-value="'0'"
>
By checked value {{data.agreed}}
</ion-checkbox>


<ion-checkbox  ng-checked='data.agreed === "yes"'
                   ng-model="data.agreed" 
                   ng-true-value="'yes'" 
                   ng-false-value="'no'"
>
By checked value {{data.agreed}}
</ion-checkbox>
```

If you can call the function by using ng-change directive like follow,

```
ng-change ="example(data.agreed)"
```

Then write a function at controller like following,

```
$scope.example =function(agreed)
{
   console.log(agreed);
   alert(agreed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
$http.post(link, { agreed: $scope.data.agreed === 1 ? true: false })
```

Comment: thats the question i was asking above

Comment: Initially it wasn't clear. That is the reason why I asked follow up questions. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

IN YOUR VIEW

```
<ion-checkbox ng-model = "isChecked" ng-change = "isSalesPersonCheck(!isChecked)">Sales Person</ion-checkbox>
```

IN CONTROLLER

```
$scope.isSalesPersonCheck = function(a){
   if(a == false)
     $scope.isChecked = true
   else
     $scope.isChecked = false//: isChecked is true when checked, false when not
     alert($scope.isChecked)
}
```